# Fibonacci Sequence help...again

Tags: recursion

I'm back again stuck on another problem:

Solve the recurrence relation:

(1) S(1)=1

(2) S(n) =nS(n−1) + n! for n≥2

Here's what I have done so far:

Expand:

**S(n) = nS(n-1) + n!**

*S(n-1) = nS(n-2)+n!*

S(n) = n [nS(n-2) + n!] + n!
=>  n^2[S(n-2) + (n^2)!] + n!

*S(n-2) = nS(n-3)+n!*

S(n) = n^2[nS(n-3)+n!] + (n^2)! + n!
=> n^3[S(n-3) + (n^3)!] + (n^2)! + n!

So....

Guess:

S(n) = n^(k) x S(n-k) + n^(k)! + n^(k-1) + k!

I tried checking it by plugging in numbers (of course after plugging in "n-1" for (k) but they did not equal each other. I know I'm doing this wrong, but I'm not sure if it's cause of my algebra or I'm just doing everything completely wrong. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated by you guys.

Comment: You're solving the recurrence backwards. Can you have S(n-2) for n>= 2? If so you get S(0) which is undefined.

Comment: `S(n-1) = nS(n-2)+n!` No, that's wrong. When you replace $n \mapsto n-1$ you get $S(n-1)=(n-1)S(n-2) + (n-1)!$.

Comment: ^exactly, you get an undefined number.

Comment: I will try solving it again with what you suggested and get back to you guys. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, solve it plugging in n which increases, starting with n + 1

Comment: Can you expand on that please. I don't follow.

Comment: @JeremyBaziw `plugging in n which increases` Why?

Comment: write out first few terms. $S(1)=1$, $S(2)=2+2!=4$, $S(3)=3*4+3!=12+6=18$, $S(4)=4*18+4!=72+24=96$, $S(5)=5*96+5!=480+120=600$. Now google first few terms, 1,4,18,96, the answer is https://oeis.org/A001563 which tells you $a(n) = n*n! = (n+1)! - n!$. Now prove the latter by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T(n)=\frac{S(n)}{n!}$, we get nicely $$T(n)=T(n-1) + 1$$ for $n\ge 2$.

And $T(1)=1$, so $T(n)=n$, and $$S(n)=n\cdot n!$$

Comment: +1 Nice. Though that's the kind of substitution that you are most likely to think at *after* you figured out the answer already.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks! Really I had not figured out the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\begin{align}
S_n & = nS_{n-1} + n! \\
 & = n\big((n-1)S_{n-2}+(n-1)!\big) + n! = n(n-1)S_{n-2} + 2 n! \\
 & = n(n-1)\big((n-2)S_{n-3} + (n-2)!\big) = n(n-1)(n-2)S_{n-3} + 3 n! \\
 & = \cdots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why is the end "+ 2n!" ..."+ 3n!"... and so on?

Comment: Because $n \cdot (n-1)! = n(n-1) \cdot (n-2)! = n!$.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I am so dumb, so literally the basic rules of a factorial right?

Comment: Right. And not seeing (even obvious) things sometimes $\ne$ dumb ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, that's not how I would start a problem like this - when you start doing algebra without a goal in mind, you just end up with variable salad.

Start by examining the first few examples and comparing them with sequences that seem related. The first four are $S(1) = 1$, $S(2) = 4$, $S(3) = 18$, $S(4) = 96$. Some possibly related sequences are $n$, $n^n$, and $n!$. The first four terms of these sequences are $1, 2, 3, 4$; $1, 4, 27, 256$; and $1, 2, 6, 24$ respectively. There doesn't seem to be an obvious relationship between $n$ and $S(n)$, nor between $n^n$ and $S(n)$; but $S(n)$ is always a multiple of $n!$. Can you see *which* multiple of $n!$ it is? That will give you a hypothesis for $S(n)$.

Now that you have a goal in mind, use algebra to prove it - verify that your hypothesis obeys both the initial condition and the recursive step.